# how to call background image using url management

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

i have implemented my project using Yii frame work. my project body background image is not calling. because i am using URL management using Yii. without URL management background image was working.

I am also using Bootstrap 3. also i removed the all css from the bootstrap css ie body contain css.

i given id for body tag and assigned url link. its not working please tell what could be a error. or overriding. suggest me

```
<body id="header_img">

#header_img{
    background-image: url(/..img/NewBG.png)no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your console for any errors (such as 404)?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this line for background

```
<style type='text/css'>

#header_img{
    background: url(../img/NewBG.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;

   }
</style>
```

Comment: your code is working fine but. when search button enter. background image is not visible

Comment: please provide the criteria and your page's details about this?

Comment: shall i pass like this                                                 background:'.Yii::app()->baseUrl.'url(../img/NewBG.png)

Comment: i passed like this also frnd  background:<?php Yii::app()->baseUrl?>url(../img/NewBG.png).. its working only url manager pages only

Comment: no you have to pass within url(you image path at browser)

Comment: as bootstrap css standards use at your css file with you image file's specific path.

Comment: i got the solution friend .. background:url(<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/img/NewBG.png)no-repeat center center fixed; this is which i required. please vote for my question

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the correct URL should be

```
background-image: url(../img/NewBG.png)no-repeat center center fixed;
```

as specified by @user2706194.

In that line, the image is relative to the location of the css

For example, assume your file index.php loads a stylesheet mystyles.css, the line above will load the image relative to the location of the CSS file, not the main HTML page.

```
Project
 |
 +-- file 1
 |    
 +-- my_code
 |  |  
 |  +-- index.php                    <== your loaded file
 |    
 +-- img
 |  |  
 |  +-- NewBG.png
 |  +-- other_img.png
 |    
 +-- assets
 |  |  
 |  +-- css
 |       |
 |       +-- mystyles.css             <== your style sheet
 |  +-- img
 |       |
 |       +-- NewBG.png                <== *** the loaded image ***
```